# Floating Action Button in linearLayout

Tags: android, floating-action-button

How can i add FAB into the second linearLayout named layout_ejercicios?

If i add this like that it doesnt appear.

I want add the FAB in the layout_ejercicios at right bottom corner.

[image]

I try to include the FAB out of the layout_ejercicios but it appears always in the top left corner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_crear_entrenamiento"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_ejercicios"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_info">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/tool_bar_ejercicios"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                    app:layout_anchor="@id/layout_ejercicios"
                    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_notas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_ejercicios"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/tool_bar_notas"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/textAreaInformacion"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:gravity="top|start"
                    android:hint="Aqui..."
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:lines="6"
                    android:overScrollMode="always"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/horaInicio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etHoraInicio"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ems="5"
                        android:hint="Hora inicio"
                        android:inputType="time"
                        android:maxLength="5"
                        android:textSize="25dp" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ubicacion"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="50dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etUbicacion"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ems="7"
                        android:hint="Ubicacion"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="20"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You need to set a LinearLayout orientation.

Comment: this works. now it appears but always at the top of the layout. if i change the layout_gravity or layout_anchorGravity the FAB keep at the top.

Comment: Try using FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout.

Comment: This post - with the comment there to put button last worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37107900/2162226

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Remove FAB from inside the Linear Layout layout_ejercicios
2. Add FAB to Relative layout activity_crear_entrenamiento and set with android:layout_alignRight="@+id/layout_ejercicios" and android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/layout_ejercicios"

Like this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_crear_entrenamiento"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_ejercicios"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_info">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar_ejercicios"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/layout_ejercicios"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/layout_ejercicios"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/layout_ejercicios"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</RelativeLayout>
```